# Creating a DoctrineCollection from a yml file

Tags: php, sql, doctrine, symfony-1.4, yaml

I need to create a DoctrineCollection from a .yml file with the Doctrine fixture syntax so i can save it later.

I guess there must be some kind of method to do this since the command symfony doctrine:data-load must parse the fixtures into sql code.

If not, is there a method to parse the fixtures to sql code and then execute it?

Comment: Did you have a look at the DoctrineFixturesBundle? I don't know if they support yml, but maybe you can work from there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can create a Collection from a yml.

But you can load some fixtures from where you want with this code:

```
// define your folder fixtures
$fixturesDirs = array_merge(
  array(sfConfig::get('sf_data_dir').'/fixtures'),
  sfApplicationConfiguration::getActive()->getPluginSubPaths('/data/fixtures')
);

$dirs = array();
foreach ($fixturesDirs as $fixturesDir)
{
  if (!is_readable($fixturesDir))
  {
    continue;
  }

  $dirs[] = $fixturesDir;
}

Doctrine_Core::loadData($dirs);
```